# AngularJS $http promise callback with undefined parameter

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-promise

I have a simple httpcall like this

```
     $http({
            "params": {
                permission
            },
            "cache": true,
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "base/authorize/any/"
        }).then(function successCallback(response){...},function failCallback(response){...});
```

When calling it the backend returns a Http 400 Bad Request. Nothing special about that.

The strange thing is: after the Backend responded the successCallback is executed. I would have expected that the faliCallback was executed.

And even stranger: inside the successCallback response is undefined.

Can any of you explain that behavior ?
I would really appreciate any help.

Edit 1:
Just in case the info is needed. This call is actually going to be intercepted by this interceptor

```
    angular.module("app").factory("UnauthorizedInterceptor",
        UnauthorizedInterceptor);

function UnauthorizedInterceptor($injector) {

    const service = {
        responseError
    };

    function responseError(response) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
            $injector.get("AuthenticationService").Logout();
            $injector.get("$state").go("home", {
                logout : true
            });
        }
    }

    return service;

}
```

Comment: Do you have any Angular interceptors set in your app?

Comment: Can you try with [$http.get()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) instead of `$http(req)`? Also try to remove `"cache": true` from your request options because it caches the response. Did you try to make this request from Postman (for example) to check the API response?

Comment: @xpander001 yes i do. i have added the interceptor code to my querstion

Comment: @MaximeLafarie using $http.get() does not make any difference. And i do want the response to be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return a rejected promise in the responseError interceptor:

```
return $q.reject(response);
```

You can check the examples in the official [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) and in [this issue on GitHub](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2609#issuecomment-44452%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B795)

Comment: you made my day :)